# Cython: Syntax for overloading operators in cppclass objects

Tags: cython

I am trying to create a struct, or some other c-like object that can use operations such as "+", "-", "<" etc

My attempt to use the syntax is this:

```
cdef cppclass pair:
double x
double y
pair operator+(pair& other):   
    p = new pair()
    p[0].x = this.x+other.x
    p[0].y = this.y+other.y
    return p[0]
cdef pair a
cdef pair b
a.x=1
a.y=2
b.x=3
b.y=4
cdef pair c
c = a + b
```

but I get this error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef cppclass pair:
    double x
    double y
    pair operator+(pair& other):   
\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_936ab3f7a1a67a849b882d3c497987c2.pyx:5:17: Syntax error in C variable declaration
```

It would also be nice to understand how to use the constructor as well, I noticed from [the docs](http://cython-docs2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html?highlight=overloaded) that there is functionality here, but without a working example I am unsure how to use it

```
cdef cppclass pair:
    double x
    double y
    pair(double x,double y)
cdef pair* a
a = new pair(1,2)
```

But I get a compiler error

```
\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_054babde51af1aba9962dd2c57e823b2.cpp(1003) : error C2661: '__pyx_t_46_cython_magic_054babde51af1aba9962dd2c57e823b2_pair::__pyx_t_46_cython_magic_054babde51af1aba9962dd2c57e823b2_pair' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

Comment: The documentation you linked is all about wrapping an _existing_ C++ class using Cython. There is an _undocumented_ ability to create new C++ classes within Cython, but it's pretty undeveloped so lots of features don't work.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the documented approach would be to write a c++ header file and then use cython with cdef extern to wrap it?

Comment: Yes - that would definitely work. I had a go at the undocumented approach and got the same errors as you. - don't think there's an obvious workround. You could try filing a bug report at github, but I suspect fixing undocumented part competed additions is low priority.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a C struct though? Why not use a Python (cdef?) class?

Comment: A cdef class would easily work, I would like to store these objects and others in a hash table, and I was thinking that cppclass would be easier to manage the memory, but I suppose it will be roughly the same.

With structs I don't need to worry at all about memory management, but with objects I think I will need to manually delete the unneeded objects.

Comment: If it were me I'd consider 2 options: 1) use cdef classes and a Python `map` (which is ultimately a hash table I believe). 2) Write the code in C++ and use `unordered_map`. Both of these options should involve minimal memory management on your part.